# Addition of data to Pre-Trained model

Tags: python, keras, pre-trained-model

For the data-set I'm working with, I have trained and saved a h5py model already using Keras. Now I have to add new data to the pre-trained model and use this new data in the training set. But I do not want to re-train the whole data-set as it took about 7 hours to train and save the model already. What are the methods that are currently available to add any new data to already trained model?

I do not want to retrain the whole model is because I do not have large data-set to add. I want to include the new data without training the model from the scratch because of time constraints.

How to add this new data?

Comment: you can load the saved weights and then train it on new data.

Comment: Typical case of transfer learning I guess. May be train a new model with the new data using the already trained model weights as the initial weights.

Comment: @SreeramTP  say If I save the weight and train it on new data, will the old data be retained?

Comment: @Eswar   In Transfer Learning we freeze the last layer and train it on the new data, If I am not wrong? But Again, Will the old data still be in the model?

Comment: The information that we seek from a model we trained is basically the weights right. So in that case I think it should work.

Comment: @Eswar Thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that you used model.save(), If you did then you can

```
from keras.models import load_model
model=load_model(<your path>)
```

and it is just your regular model, you can train it, predict with it whatever you want

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_data, train_labels,epochs=epochs,batch_size=batch_size,validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
```

and whatever you want to do

Comment: Yes, I have saved the model as such, Now will this add the new data to the pre-trained model is the question. I can for sure predict with new data but I need this new accurate data into my training set with the already existing model.

Comment: if you load your model as stated in the answer then it will act as if your model before you saved it , it can train more data without any issues using the training method that you used before albeit with new dataset .